How do you take a users input and parse the string into individual characters? React Native and typescript
My goal is to turn a message such as hello into an array of [h,e,l,l,o]. Every other question and answer uses the split method to turn a list into an array, but no one would type h,e,l,l,o so that i could use the split method targeting commas. I feel like the answer is super basic and i am overlooking it, but I cannot find a solution that works.
I have tried using text.split with many separators but none would work. I just want to tuen any string whether its one word or multiple into an array of single characters.

I'm curious as to what do you need this for? A string in Typescript and Javascript already behaves much like an array. You index it like an array, for example "hello"[0] equals to "e" and so on, it also has a length property like an array, so that "hello".length equals to 5.

"but no one would type h,e,l,l,o so that i could use the split method targeting commas"—have you really seen examples that require "h,e,l,l,o" as an input? I suspect not. Try re-reading what you've found. If necessary, run the code.

Hey Chris, the information I have found sets the delimiter as what it is separating the string by. Typically people use it for taking a string thats a list delimited by commas to separate them into individual strings. I just want to take one word and separate it into letters.

You have mentioned text.split, why not use
text.split('')

Another approach is to use：
Array.from(text)

